# App displays perfectly on emulator but not on design preview?

Tags: android, android-studio

[Edit: new image displaying rendering errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCZVK.jpg)(first time asking a question, sorry if I've left anything out!)
I haven't come across a solution for this. On google there's only solutions to the reverse of this where the emulator isn't showing what the design preview is!
It must be something to with my themes because I have rendering problems:
    `"Failed to find style 'textInputStyle' in current theme".`
However I've tried to switch between every theme with no improvement.

Honestly just confused as to why it would work perfectly on the emulator but not on the preview, It would be handier to have this function working rather than building and running for every single change, thanks!

This is my styles.xml:
`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorText</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorText</item>
</style>
```

`

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cathy.myapplication.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cathy.myapplication.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cathy.myapplication.activities.UsersListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

[image: Link to image displaying emulator and design view]

Comment: did you see the error icon at the top-left corner click on that icon you will find the error

Comment: try invalidate and restart android studio.

Comment: show the red top-left corner saying? please so we could help

Comment: Linked a new image at the top showing the errors! Also previously tried cleaning and rebuilding, and invalidating caches and restarting prior to posting the question with no luck!

Comment: if any of the solution I provided please up vote and accept so that It could help more! if not get in comments to resolve @Cathy-Orla

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons causing this issue! lets see them one by one!

In android studio cache is one issue  so first follow the solution 1!

**SOLUTION ONE**

**"1: INVALIDATING CACHE AND RESTART"**

As in your provided styles you are not changing any builtin theme style then this input is one clear sign that android studio is not properly responding with the design part of the project that you require to build!

So GO to ***FILE*** menu ==> **Invalidate Cache and Restart** and see if that works! on restart !    this should!

**SOLUTION TWO**

**"1: Selecting the proper design render sdk option"**

In the image I encircled the option to select by default it select what's more suitable but Softwares do make tiny mistakes too! so try changing the sdk version there! if you have multiple sdk platforms installed for android!    This will refresh the design in the design area!

[image]

**SOLUTION Three**

**"3: Updating the sdk from settings or Downloading most famously used Android sdk api"**

go in your settings of android and open sdk manager! download any other android api for android install it completely!

**SOLUTION Four**

**"4 Update your android studio to latest build tools and latest apis"**

Go in Help Menu and press **Check for updates** and follow the rules!

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above worked but I appreciate the effort, thank you!

Comment: ok what is your android studio version! what is your sdk, and what are your build tools!

Comment: did you try to update your appcompat library version in your project's build gradle file?

Comment: is the same case with all other projects or is this only with this one?

Comment: This is only my second project so I am new to this, currently updating my android api 28 because I noted that it was only partially installed, so I'm installing the missing packages now. My android studio version is the latest because I checked for updates! I haven't tried updating my appcompat library version, I can look into that next, thanks!

Comment: sweet! do make sure that one sdk platform is completely installed! Happy android

Answer (score 0):

Change your build file in android. I had alpha3 before.

dependencies {

```
.....

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

.......

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

.....

}

Comment: thank you! i had the same alpha3, changing it to alpha1 fixed it