# Android Studio's Project Preview is Blank in a New Project

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I just started learning some Android Studio, but when I create a project, the "Hello World" template isn't showing on the preview window, even if I make changes or add elements to the xml layout.
On my phone it shows perfectly, but I can't make it work on the IDE.

[image: Here's my screen]

Comment: Probably just a bug in Android Studio, the preview window is really unreliable

Comment: its not android bug! its just the sdk platform tools that are causing to bring the beta version of appcompat library I have already a question answered on this issue ! lemme get you the link of that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078995/app-displays-perfectly-on-emulator-but-not-on-design-preview/51082351#51082351
see this up vote both answers because they will help you ^_^

Comment: Thank you @Rizwanatta changing the implements in build.gradle solves the problem!

Comment: @AgustínClemente please up vote our answers! that would really help! thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a known bug. Here are the many options to fix it:**

- Build > Clean Project
- Build > Rebuild project
- File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
- If all else fails, go to your styles.xml located in `res/values`. Make sure you're using the `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` theme, instead of the default. (If you want a dark theme, do the obvious and change it to `Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar`

**Why this happens/Why this fixes it:**

For some reason, Android Studio still uses the deprecated `ActionBar` by default and I don't think the layout editor supports it anymore. Thus it's crashing anonymously.

**To use a `Toolbar` since the `ActionBar` is deprecated, follow this link:**

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

(^  You can probably skip Step 1 in the above link)

Comment: Thank you! step No. 4 worked for me, but how can I do if I want to use the action bar?

Comment: @AgustínClemente The `ActionBar` is deprecated, as in you shouldn't use it anymore sense it's old. I will edit my answer to give further information.

Comment: If I solved the problem, please mark it as answered when you can.